# Does Apple Music include FULL iTunes Match functionality, or not?

Tags: apple-music, itunes-match, apple-one

I've been unable to get a simple, clear conclusive/official answer to this question:

Does Apple Music truly include *all* of the feature set of iTunes Match?

Bonus question below.

My situation:

1. I am a subscriber to both iTunes Match and Apple Music
2. I'm considering upgrading to the Apple One family plan since for just a tiny bit more money over the year, I would get a lot more iCloud storage.  I really don't care about any of the other things in One.
3. If upgrading to One, I would want to drop iTunes Match which renews end of this month.

If I were to do this, would I lose anything when iTunes Match drops, given I still have Apple Music?  Wondering what I've been paying for all these years that I've had both.

From my research so far, I'm getting very confusing and often contradictory information on whether or not iTunes Match is now a part of Apple Music, if only certain specific features of iTunes match have been rolled into Apple Music, or if they are in fact totally different things (still) that address very different issues and therefore both are still needed if you are say, a musician who has a lot of "unknown" tracks in your library that will never be matched by Apple Music.

Comment: I _think_ Apple Music won't allow you to have songs that are not available on Apple Music uploaded to the Cloud for streaming/syncing with other devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I got the other day direct from an Apple support phone rep - after quite a lot of being put on hold while she went and conferred with various people including engineering - was that the only difference is that iTunes Match gives you separate, additional storage for your uploaded music, such that if you cancel Apple Music you will still have access to anything you uploaded yourself.  Anything downloaded from the Apple Music library of course, would not be playable.  I have elected to cancel my iTunes Match subscription.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article on *Macworld*](https://www.macworld.com/article/225687/apple-music-faq-plans-prices-features.html) from December 2021, if you want music on your Mac that isn't on Apple Music to get uploaded to your library so you can access it on other devices, you still need iTunes Match.

> If your personal music collection has a lot of rare tracks and content
> that you can’t get through Apple Music, then you may want to consider
> keeping both subscriptions.

Comment: Yes this has been my belief and it's why I've paid for iTunes Match for years.  But I keep reading, including from people purporting to be quoting Apple, that "Apple Music includes the functionality of iTunes Match".  My gut feeling is that Apple Music includes *some* functionality, but I'm unable to determine which that might be.  I would really like an official, clear statement from Apple somewhere if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, I have iTunes Match features with Apple Music. I have an Apple One suscription and I do have access to all my music in all my devices, a lot of my music is not available on streaming services. What you need to do is turn on Sync on the settings of the Music app.